# Change upload location of a Google Form to a Google Sites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-sites

I need help please!

I am making a repository of proyects in Google sites. This repository is a Data base in Google Sheets feeded by a Google Form, and has an interfase in Google Sites using Awesome Tables.

My problem is that each Google Form has a file upload which the documents are automaticaly saved into my drive, but I need that this files are saved automaticaly to Google Sites so anyone can consult and change them.

Google Sites has specific buttons that can upload files, so I reckon that I can make a script saves the files directly to Googel Sites or use the link of the file in my Drive and activate this button to upload the Files.

I figured I can use this script and add the Google Sites destination, I just don't know how. Sorry for my lack of Script knowledge.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) { 
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); 
  var ft = e.values.slice(1); //This is where are the file url were located 
  var fA = ft[0].split(','); 
  for(var i = 0; i < fA.length; i++) { 
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fA[i].slice(fA[i].indexOf("=")+1)); 
    Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": "FolderId"}]}, file.getId()); 
    Utilities.sleep(2000); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: I figured I can use this script and add the Google Sites destination, I just don't know how. Sorry for my lack of Script knowledge.function 

onFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var ft=e.values.slice(1);//This is where are the file url were located
  var fA=ft[0].split(',');
  for(var i=0;i<fA.length;i++) {
    var file=DriveApp.getFileById(fA[i].slice(fA[i].indexOf("=")+1));
    Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": "FolderId"}]}, file.getId());
    Utilities.sleep(2000);
  } 
}

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add the code you have already tried. Use the edit functionality to improve your question, instead of posting your code as a comment.